# Erro ao tentar acessar campos de um formulário

Tags: javascript, html

Estou estudando Javascript e montando este projeto de acordo com o que vou aprendendo e pesquisando, estou cadastrando um nome filme em uma tabela através de um formulário, quando eu preencho esse formulário retorna o seguinte erro:

> ```
> principal.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
> at HTMLButtonElement. (principal.js:42)
> (anonymous) @ principal.js:42
> ```

Segue meu HTML e Javascript:

```js
//Retorna a lista de todos os elementos que combinam com o critério de busca.
var dvd = document.querySelectorAll(".info-dvd");



//algoritimo calcula quantas linhas existem na tabela
var quantidade = document.querySelectorAll(".filmes");
var total = document.querySelector(".info-total");
var valorTotal = quantidade.length;
total.textContent = valorTotal;



//Para cada elemento retornado executa uma ação dependendo do seu conteúdo.
dvd.forEach((e) => {
  var dvdInfo = e.textContent;
  switch (dvdInfo) {  //Troquei os if por um controle de fluxo switch por questão de legibilidade
    case "Sim": //fall through case para dvdInfo == "Sim" || dvdInfo == "Não".
    case "Não":
                 console.log("tudo funcionando");
                 break;
    case "":
                 e.textContent = "O Campo não pode estar vazio!"
                 console.log("campo está vazio");
                 e.style.color = "white";
                 e.classList.add("mensagemErro");

                 break;
    default:
                 e.textContent = "Preecha o campo com Sim ou Não";
                 console.log("campo invalido");
                 break;
  }
});

        //Impede que o botão recarregue a página e limpe o formulário!
        var botaoAdicionar = document.querySelector("#btn-enviar");
        botaoAdicionar.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //criando novos linhas na tabela
        var form = document.querySelector("#form");
        var filme = form.filme.value;
        var genero = form.genero.value;
        var dvd = form.dvd.value;
        var dimas = form.dimas.value;
        var bruna = form.bruna.value;

        console.log(filme);
        console.log(genero);
        console.log(dvd);
        console.log(dimas);
        console.log(bruna);

    });
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }

body, html{

    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.bgbody {
    background-image: url("../img/teste.jpg");
    background-position: top;;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display :block;
    width : 100%;
}


header{
    background-color: #333;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

header h1{
    font-size: 2em;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
header h2{
    font-size: 2em;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

header .container:before{
    content: '';
    display:inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.container{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

section{
    margin: 2em 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

section h2{
    font-size: 3em;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
.dimas{
    color: white;
    background:  #0e9af1;
}
.bruna{
    color: white;
    background: #00e673;
}
.info-total{
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.total{
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
th{
    font-size: 20px;
}
td{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}
tr{
    text-align: center;
}
.custom{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.changeth{
    color: black;
}
table{
    background-color: white;
}
.mensagemErro{
    background: red;
    color: white;
}

label{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.btnEnviar{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.formTitle{
    font-size: 22px;
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;

}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Brumas - Controle de Filmes & Séries</title>
            <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

        </head>
        <body class="bgbody">
            <header>
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="a">Brumas - Controle de Filmes & Séries</h1>
                </div>
            </header>
            <main>
        <section class="container">
                            <h2>Controle</h2>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="changeth">Nome</th>
                                <th class="changeth">Gênero</th>
                                <th class="changeth">Possui DVD</th>
                                <th class="dimas">Dimas</th>
                                <th class="bruna">Bruna</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tabela-pacientes">
                            <tr class="filmes" >
                                <td class="info-nome">Invocação do Mal</td>
                                <td class="info-genero">Terror</td>
                                <td class="info-dvd">Sim</td>
                                <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
                                <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="filmes" >
                                <td class="info-nome">Invocação do Mal 2</td>
                                <td class="info-genero">Terror</td>
                                <td class="info-dvd">Sim</td>
                                <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
                                <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="filmes" >
                                <td class="info-nome">O Exorcista</td>
                                <td class="info-genero">Terror</td>
                                <td class="info-dvd">Sim</td>
                                <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
                                <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="filmes" >
                                <td class="info-nome">Jogos Vorazes</td>
                                <td class="info-genero">Ação/Ficção científica</td>
                                <td class="info-dvd">Sim</td>
                                <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
                                <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="filmes" >
                                <td class="info-nome">A Hora do Pesadelo</td>
                                <td class="info-genero">Terror</td>
                                <td class="info-dvd">Não</td>
                                <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
                                <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="filmes" >
                                <td class="info-nome"></td>
                                <td class="info-genero">Comédia</td>
                                <td class="info-dvd">Não</td>
                                <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
                                <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="filmes" >
                                <td class="info-nome">UM Príncepe em Nova York</td>
                                <td class="info-genero">Comédia</td>
                                <td class="info-dvd">Não</td>
                                <td class="info-dimas">Sim</td>
                                <td class="info-bruna">Sim</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="total" >
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td class="bg-success total">Total:</td>

                                <td class="bg-dark info-total">0</td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>

            </section>
<hr>

<div class="container">
<h2 class="formTitle">Adicionar Filmes</h2>
<form  id="form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label id="filme">Nome do Filme</label>
      <input placeholder="Coloque o nome do Filme ou Franquia" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" required>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label name="genero">Gênero</label>
      <input placeholder="Coloque o Gênero do Filme. Ex: Terror" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" required>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label name="dvd">Possui Dvd?</label>
            <input placeholder="Possui Media de DVD? Sim ou Não" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" required>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label name="dimas">Dimas</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" required>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label name="bruna">Bruna</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
        Confirmo envio do formulário
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="btn-enviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
</form>
</div>
            </main>
            <!--<footer>
                <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-dark">
            <h3 class="custom">Copyright @ Brumas</h3>
            </div>
    </footer>-->

            <script src="js/principal.js">
</script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema encontra-se nesta parte do código:

> ```js
> var form = document.querySelector("#form");
> var filme = form.filme.value;
> var genero = form.genero.value;
> var dvd = form.dvd.value;
> var dimas = form.dimas.value;
> var bruna = form.bruna.value;
> ```

Note que você está tentando obter os elementos referentes aos campos pelo próprio formulário. E isso é possível, de acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#Accessing_the_forms_elements):

> You can also get the form's element by using its `name` attribute as a key of the `form`. [...]

Em tradução livre:

Você também pode obter os elementos do formulário utilizando o atributo `name` como chave de `form`.

Isso significa que, desde que os campos do seu formulário possuam um atributo `name`, você pode acessá-los a partir do elemento do formulário.

O problema é que nenhum dos seus campos tem o atributo `name`. Vejamos, por exemplo, o primeiro deles:

> ```html
> <div class="form-group col-md-6">
>   <label id="filme">Nome do Filme</label>
>   <input placeholder="..." type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" required>
> </div>
> ```

Note que, apesar de possuir um `id`, não possui um atributo `name`. Para corrigir, bastaria colocar o atributo `name` como, neste caso, `filme`. Assim:

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label id="filme">Nome do Filme</label>
  <input name="filme" placeholder="..." type="text" class="form-control" id="filme" required>
</div>
```

Além disso, convém colocar o `id` como `filme` também (para fazer referência ao atributo `for` do `<label>`).

Basta fazer isso para cada um dos campos.

---

Mas é válido ressaltar que a própria documentação (que mencionei anteriormente) recomenda o uso da propriedade [`elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) para acessar os campos do que obtê-los diretamente através da instância do formulário, já que esta última abordagem pode abrir espaço para conflitos de nomes.

Portanto, ao invés de utilizar, por exemplo:

```
form.filme.value;
```

Utilize:

```
form.elements.filme.value;
```

De modo que `filme` é o `name` do campo. :)

Para saber mais sobre o elemento `<form>`, [consulte a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement). Tem várias informações importantes nessa página.

Comment: Cara excelente resposta!
Mas eu descobri meu erro eu estava colando name no label ao invés do input, falta de atenção minha!
Uma pergunta se eu não colocar o elements pode dar conflito é isso?

Comment: Sim, o formulário contém várias outras propriedades além dos campos, o que pode gerar conflitos. Ao usar `elements`, que é uma propriedade que contém exclusivamente os campos, você elimina a possibilidade de conflitos. :) @dimascamillo

Answer (score -1):

Outra abordagem mais simples seria obter os elementos direto pelos ids dos campos que você deseja Ex.

var email = document.getElementByid('inputEmail4').value